# How to use upstart tasks to create a new file with today's date?

Tags: command-line, upstart, makefile

1. I am trying to use [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) to create a new file with today's date.
2. I have created a file called "Open.conf" at `/home/myusername/.config/upstart`
3. I have the following lines in that file:

   ```
   description "Desktop Open Task"
   start on desktop-start
   task
   script
       NOW=$(date +'%Y%m%d')
       NOW=${NOW:2:6}
       FILE="/home/path/to/location/${NOW}D.txt"
       test -e $FILE || touch $FILE
       test -s $FILE || echo -e "DATE: ${NOW} >> $FILE
       xdg-open $FILE
   end script
   ```
4. I have checked all of the above lines compiles in the terminal and does the desired tasks
5. I have also checked that if I replace the above with something for example, `chromium-browser` or `firefox "http://www.google.com"` then it gets executed at start up.
6. However the above lines of code doesn't execute at startup.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Here is a quick solution which works: I create a bash file called "Start.sh" and put all the lines of the code in there. (Don't forget to make the bash file as an executable). Then in the "Open.conf" I just ask that "Start.sh" be executed by adding instead `home/path/to/file/Start.sh`. So it works. Would still like to learn why the above doesn't work.

Comment: Could I ask why *upstart* and not *startup applications*? as you are dealing with some GUI tools

Comment: Yes, please explain why you need to use upstart and not just load a script from your Startup Applications (or autostart file).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the script is executed by `/bin/dash` instead of `/bin/bash`. Therefore, the solution of sneetsher creation of a script which state `/bin/bash` via shebang as interpreter should work.

Comment: Interesting. Could you you elaborate a bit more? What is sneetsher?